# delete all users from group

Tags: command-line, user-management, passwd-file

In ubuntu, how do you delete all users from a group using the bash command line?

The group is called grp1 and it's at /etc/group
It don't care whether the actual group remains or not. I just want the members gone.
(Any user who is a member of that group should be removed from /etc/passwd)

Answer (score 2):

First you find all files owned by said group and assign them to a new group if you so desire (probably best, but not sure)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159244/find-files-belonging-to-a-group ,

You then delete the group via sed `sudo sed -i -e 's/group_to_remove/d' /etc/group`

Answer (score 1):

Are there really so many users that this need be automated? This is one of those things where the balance between saving a couple of minutes and completely destroying your system teeters the wrong way. I wouldn't automate this unless we were talking about dozens of users.

If it's that many, I would suggest starting with generating a list of the users you want to remove:

```
grep -Po '^grp1:.*:.*:\K\w+' /etc/group > bad_users
```

If that's still too many to handle, you can grep them out of `/etc/passwd`, generating a new one.

```
grep -vFf bad_users /etc/passwd > new_passwd
```

Review that (eg `diff new_passwd /etc/passwd`) and if you like it, move the contents over. There's still an amount of cleanup to make off the back of this (home directories, spools, etc) depending on how substantial the users were but given the variance there, I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say the group gid is 2000

To delete any user who's primary group is set to 2000

```
awk -F: "(\$4==2000) { print \$1 }" /etc/passwd | sudo xargs userdel
```

some of you might be freaking out by now seeing xargs and userdel together :)

Comment: And what does this do to files owned by this group? :-)

Comment: the question title is 'delete all users from group' so it's kinda out of scope

Comment: but breaking stuff is generally not a good idea ;)